# How do you get a list of data from a table in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a table in Google Sheets of people and what events they've attended in the form:

```
          Event 1        Event 2         Event 3
Alice       1                              1
Bob         1              1
Charlie                                    1
```

How can I transform this into a list of people->events like this?

```
Alice       Event 1
Alice       Event 3
Bob         Event 1
Bob         Event 2
Charlie     Event 3
```

Ideally it would be dynamic so that you could add an Event 4 or another person and the list would update.

EDIT: final formula was

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(B2:D="",,A2:A&"♦"&B1:D1)), "♦"), "where Col2 is not null", 0))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(B2:D="",,A2:A&"♦"&B1:D1)), "♦"), 
 "where Col2 is not null", 0))
```

Comment: thank you for this! what does the diamond symbol mean here?

Comment: this works mostly but leaves #VALUE! errors where the table is not filled in:
Alice Event 1
#VALUE! 
Alice Event 3
Bob Event 1
Bob Event 2
#VALUE! 
#VALUE! 
#VALUE! 
Charlie Event 3

Comment: modified to =ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(FILTER(FLATTEN(IF(B2:D4="",,A2:A&"♦"&B1:D1)), FLATTEN(B2:D4)<>""), "♦"), "where Col1 is not null", 0)), adding the filter seemed to fix it

Comment: @NicoleGerber diamond symbol is just an ordinary separator mark for SPLIT. answer updated